# How to add css file to wordpress theme or plugin? Is it compulsory to create custom css file?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. Is it compulsory to add custom css to wordpress?

Can we change in its style.css?

Comment: Yes you can add css code into style.css but better is to add custom css which will helpful in future to identify code done by developer.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not compulsory to create custom CSS file But it is a better practice to not use core theme CSS for plugins.

To add custom CSS in wordpress add the below cod to theme/theme-name/functions.php file :

```
function hook_css()
{
 wp_enqueue_style( 'unique-css-name', 'your-css-path/style.css' ); // includes CSS file
}

add_action('wp_head','hook_css'); // calls hook_css in head block
```

Since you are new to WordPress you must know wp_head is a hook which is automatically called in head tag